# Python - dir() - how can I differentiate between functions/method and simple attributes?

Tags: python

`dir()` returns a list of all the defined names, but it is annoying to try to call function I see listed only to discover it is actually an attribute, or to try to access an attribute only to discover it is actually a callable.  How can I get `dir()` to be more informative?

Comment: `attrs = [a for a in dir(obj) if not callable(a)]` and `funcs = [a for a in dir(obj) if callable(a)]`

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi That won't work- `dir` gives strings.

Comment: Sorry, `attrs = [a for a in dir(obj) if not callable(getattr(obj, a))]`

Comment: Just FYI, `callable()` also finds classes because they are callable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show a list of the defined names in a module, for example the math module, and their types you could do:

```
[(name,type(getattr(math,name))) for name in dir(math)]
```

getattr(math,name) returns the object (function, or otherwise) from the math module, named by the value of the string in the variable "name". For example type(getattr(math,'pi')) is 'float'

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to make `dir` 'more informative' as you put it, but you can use the [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) functions:

```
[(a, 'func' if callable(getattr(obj, a)) else 'attr') for a in dir(obj)]
```

---

Obviously functions are still attributes themselves, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `getmembers` function in `inspect`. You can get a similar result to James's one by

```
from inspect import getmembers

getmembers(obj)  # => ...
```

For more information, please take a look at:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers

Answer (score 0):

You can see details on this way :

```
for functions_variables_list in dir( module_name ):
  print(functions_variables_list, type( getattr(module_name, functions_variables_list)))
```

PS: For default function details see: [dir()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_dir.asp), [type()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/), [getattr()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-getattr-method/)